# How do I perform Gram-Schmidt on floating point vectors with epsilons in them?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, orthonormal, floating-point

Let $\epsilon$ be a small positive number such that $1+\epsilon$ and $3+2\epsilon$ are machine numbers but $3+2\epsilon + \epsilon^{2}$ is computed to be $3 + 2\epsilon $.  Now, let the (classical) Gram-Schmidt process be applied to the three vectors $v_{1} = fl(1 + \epsilon, 1, 1)^{T} $, $v_{2} = fl(1, 1+\epsilon, 1)^{T}$, $v_{3} = fl(1, 1, 1 + \epsilon)^{T}$.  **Verify that the supposedly orthonormal base produced by the computer will be**

$\mathbf{x_{1}=fl[1/\sqrt{3+2\epsilon}]v_{1}}$,

$\mathbf{x_{2}=fl[1/\sqrt{2}](-1,1,0)^{T}}$,

$\mathbf{x_{3}=fl[1/\sqrt{2}](-1,0,1)^{T}}$.

I am so incredibly lost because I have no idea how to perform Gram-Schmidt on numbers that look like this!

Could someone at least show me how to get $x_{2}$ ($x_{1}$ is easy enough)? **If I could see how the operations with $\epsilon$'s and floats are supposed to work in calculating $x_{1}$, I could probably figure out the rest of it myself.** (I assume we're supposed to solve this problem by actually performing Gram-Schmidt on $v_{1}$, $v_{2}$, and $v_{3}$; correct me if I'm wrong).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here the calculation for $x_2:$
$$u_1=v_1, \quad <u_1,u_1>=(1+\epsilon)^2 + 1 +1 = 3+2\epsilon$$
$$u_2 = v_2 - \frac{<u_1,v_2>}{<u_1,u_1>}u_1
=(1,1+\epsilon,1)^T-\frac{(1+\epsilon)\times 1+ 1\times (1+\epsilon)+1\times 1}{3+2\epsilon}u_1=
(1,1+\epsilon,1)^T-\frac{3+2\epsilon}{3+2\epsilon}u_1=
(1,1+\epsilon,1)^T-(1+\epsilon,1,1)^T = (-\epsilon, \epsilon, 0)^T
$$
Now $|u_2|=\sqrt{\epsilon^2 + \epsilon^2 + 0} = \epsilon \sqrt{2}$ and therefore the floating point approximation:
$$x_2=\frac{u_2}{|u_2|}=fl(1/\sqrt{2}) (-1,1,0)^T$$

Comment: thank you! I just finished it myself a second ago. Your hints earlier were very helpful!